# Exp:resso Store not sending email order confirmation

Tags: expresso-store

Not receiving emails from Exp:resso Store 1.65 when order completed. Nether order conformation to the buyer or the notification to the store manager are generating, you can see the order when I login. It seemed to start when I migrated the site to hosting on nexcess.net. Any ideas, lost.

Comment: Did you check if mail is received in the spam box? Can you send email with a simple php script? `mail('to@url.nl','The subject','the body tekst')`

Comment: What protocol are you using to send email? PHP Mail, Sendmail, or SMTP? If PHP Mail or Sendmail aren't working then it's most likely those which are missing on your hosting setup. I'd recommend trying SMTP and using an SMTP service provider which will allow you to track your email en route. A service such as SendGrid provides a free account so sign up there and give that a test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was the server send mail. Nothing to do with Exp-resso or EE. It was not pointing the the MX record correctly. Just a server setting.

Answer (score 2):

Per Ian's advice in the comments, I highly recommend using [Sendgrid](http://sendgrid.com/) or a similar service for sending email. Sending email directly from your own server is highly unreliable, and likely to get caught in a spam filter or even outright blocked in this day and age. Sendgrid is free for up to 200 emails per day, so there is really no reason not to use it.